# html tags in an R markdown document compiled to pdf

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I'm trying to use R Markdown to create a pdf document, and I'm having problems using certain html tags. For example, the R markdown document

```
---
output: pdf_document
---

<pre>
code1
</pre>

<code>
code2
</code>

<pre><code>
code3
</code></pre>
```

compiles to give

```
code2
```

when the desired output is

```
code1
code2
code3
```

with some nice formatting for `code3`. But if I compile to html (`output: html_document` instead of `output: pdf_document` in the metadata), the problem is solved.

I'm compiling with TexShop on a Mac using the engine below.

```
#!/bin/bash
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/bin/Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render(\"$1\", encoding='UTF-8')"
```

I suspect that I'm not allowed to user certain html tags when I compile to a pdf, but I haven't been able to find any guidelines on this.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using raw HTML for this when Markdown has its own way to markup code?

Comment: I could bound the code by 2 sets of 3 backticks each, but I don't like the aesthetic, and I don't have control of the style.

Comment: What about the Markdown standard: indented code blocks?

Comment: Indented blocks compile the same for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to remember that the PDF format is not HTML and knows nothing of HTML tags. When a document is converted to PDF, each piece of the document needs to be converted to its corresponding PDF entity. Therefore, when you introduce non-standard raw HTML into your document, the converter can easily be confused.

Of course, how the converter works under the hood could have some effect on the output as well. For example, if the tool you are using converts the Markdown to HTML and then converts that HTML to PDF, then the raw HTML may have a better chance of being mapped properly. However, if the tool goes straight from a parse tree (list of tokens) to the output format, then it may not know anything about the raw HTML (unless it is also an HTML parser). The point is that using raw HTML adds another potential layer of failure when converting to PDF. My suggestion would be to avoid it if at all possible when you indent to convert to PDF (remember Markdown was originally intended to output HTML only).

As it turns out, Markdown already offers a way (or two; depending on which implementation you are using) to mark up code blocks: [indented code blocks](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode) (and possibly fenced code blocks). Interestingly, the HTML they output is the same as the raw HTML that you have found to work. Perhaps that should provide a clue that the other two possibilities you tried are not valid.

In fact, the HTML Spec is pretty clear that code blocks must be wrapped in `<pre><code>` tags. The `<pre>` tag is a block level tag, so it does not need to be wrapped in any parent tags. However, the `<pre>` tag does not identify its contents as being "code". Therefore, it should never be assumed that it contains "code" itself. On the other hand, the `<code>` tag is not a block level tag. It must be wrapped by a block level tag (like `<pre>` or `<p>`...). And the `<code>` tag is the only tag which marks content as being "code". Therefore, the only valid way to mark up a code block in HTML is to wrap it in `<pre><code>` tags. As it turns out, when you do that, it works. Therefore, my conclusion is that the converter is being confused by invalid HTML and failing (as it should).

So, in conclusion, either use native Markdown methods for marking up code or, if you must use raw HTML, stick to valid HTML.

Comment: You have thoroughly answered my original question. Still, I'm not satisfied with how the pdf output looks. And unfortunately, I can't always get away with HTML, and I occasionally want to show code in languages other than R. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815357/fenced-code-blocks-when-converting-r-markdown-to-pdf has my follow-up question.