# fenced code blocks when converting R Markdown to pdf

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

When I compile an R Markdown document to an HTML document, the non-R code blocks are formatted nicely. But when I compile the following R Markdown document to pdf, the only added code formatting is in the font. There is no shading, fencing, highlighting, etc.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```
code
```
````

I don't want to micromanage the output, I just want to add some common-sense formatting to clearly separate the code from the prose. I'm using TeXShop on a MAc with the engine below.

```
#!/bin/bash
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/bin/Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render(\"$1\", encoding='UTF-8')"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ```` ``` ```` you introduce a plain markdown code block but not a `knitr` code chunk. But the output you expect (fencing, highlighting, shading) is the style `knitr` adds to its code blocks.

Therefore, use ```` ```{r} ```` to wrap code in `knitr` chunks (use `eval = FALSE` if you don't want the code to be evaluated). This can also be used for non-R code blocks: As long as the code is not evaluated, the language doesn't matter.

However, for non-R code this will lead to wrong or missing syntax highlighting. To get the correct syntax highlighting, use the [option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) `engine` if the language is among the [supported language engines](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/).

The example below shows a pain markdown block, an evaluated and and unevaluated R code chunk, a (unevaluated) Python chunk without highlighting and finally two (unevaluated) Python chunks with correct highlighting.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document
---

```
Plain markdown code block.
```


```{r}
print("This is a knitr code chunk.")
```

```{r, eval = FALSE}
print("This is a knitr code chunk that isn't evaluated.")
```


Chunk with Python code (borrowed from http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/2706569), *wrong* (no) highlighting:
```{r, eval = FALSE}
if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
      yield self._leftchild
```

Chunk with Python code, *correct* highlighting:
```{r, eval = FALSE, engine = "python"}
if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
      yield self._leftchild
```

Chunk with Python code, *correct* highlighting (alternative notation):
```{python, eval = FALSE}
if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
      yield self._leftchild
```
````

[image: Output]